# C# web app is using none hard coded path of dev pc showing up on server logs

Tags: c#

I have an odd happening where the C# app I have made in VS2012 is working just fine on my pc under IIS, but when I put it up on the server what happens is I'm logging errors like,

```
    2013-07-02 10:08:44,572 [5] ERROR Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Views.NVelocity.NVelocityViewEngine [(null)] <(null)> - Could not render view
    NVelocity.Exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'theme_skin_url' in  stellar.Services.themeService threw exception System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at stellar.Services.themeService.theme_skin_url(site site, String theme, String mode, String type) in d:\._GIT_\HIV PROJECT\stellar\Services\site_controlls\themeService.cs:line 292
    at stellar.Services.themeService.theme_skin_url(String type) in d:\._GIT_\HIV PROJECT\stellar\Services\site_controlls\themeService.cs:line 280
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at NVelocity.Runtime.Parser.Node.ASTMethod.Execute(Object o, IInternalContextAdapter context)
    at NVelocity.Runtime.Parser.Node.ASTReference.Execute(Object o, IInternalContextAdapter context)
    at NVelocity.Runtime.Parser.Node.ASTReference.Render(IInternalContextAdapter context, TextWriter writer)
    at NVelocity.Runtime.Parser.Node.ASTBlock.Render(IInternalContextAdapter context, TextWriter writer)
    at Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Views.NVelocity.CustomDirectives.CaptureForDirective.Render(IInternalContextAdapter context, TextWriter writer, INode node)
    at NVelocity.Runtime.Parser.Node.ASTDirective.Render(IInternalContextAdapter context, TextWriter writer)
    at NVelocity.Runtime.Parser.Node.SimpleNode.Render(IInternalContextAdapter context, TextWriter writer)
    at NVelocity.Template.Merge(IContext context, TextWriter writer)
    at Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Views.NVelocity.NVelocityViewEngine.RenderLayout(String layoutName, String contents, IContext ctx, TextWriter output)
    at Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Views.NVelocity.NVelocityViewEngine.ProcessLayoutRecursively(StringWriter writer, IEngineContext context, IController controller, IControllerContext controllerContext, IContext ctx, TextWriter finalOutput)
    at Castle.MonoRail.Framework.Views.NVelocity.NVelocityViewEngine.Process(String viewName, TextWriter output, IEngineContext context, IController controller, IControllerContext controllerContext)
```

Now you'll see that it's looking for something in

`d:\._GIT_\HIV PROJECT\stellar\Services\site_controlls\themeService.cs`

but on the server where it's running it's really

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain.com\Services\site_controlls\themeService.cs`

Now I know for sure it's not hard coded on the server, and I even went to the length of near hard coding the root path in the webconfig on the method that gets the app path.

```
        public static String root_path() {

            NameValueCollection section = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("site_config");
            string setting = section["root"];
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(setting)) return setting;


            String path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative("~");
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path)) return path;

            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath).Replace("bin", "");
            return path;
        }
```

Where the web.config has

```
  <site_config>
        <add key="installed" value="False" />
        <add key="root" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain.com" />
  </site_config>
```

So it's confusing that when I get the logs of the server I end up with the path in the error log of the dev pc I work on not the server.

The question is, other then hard coded my me, what condition would allow for the path of where a app is not loaded, is not used but the path of where it was developed?  Is it in the project dll?

Comment: Off the top of my head I think this happens when you build in DEBUG mode or with PDB files but I am not at computer with VS to test that theory! Try with a RELEASE build and without PDB files to see if you still get that path.

Comment: will try, but yes I have been just pushing the debug build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folders you see there are taken from the projects debug symbols. They are only there for you to know where the files were located on the build computer. 
This information is usually not accessible from your code so the error you are encountering is probably something else in the implementation of `theme_skin_url`.

Comment: Yes in deeded when I used the release build as @Belogix suggested and this highlights your assessment.  Thank you for clearing that up.